# Is there a way to have a python script output a list to all folders called desktop on the system

Tags: python, directory

I am trying to write a python script that outputs a list of all directories on a drive called desktop. The problem I am running into is that I can only list folders one layer deep, also I would like to check drives that have been mounted besides the c drive. I know you can check for a certain file and output the path to that file using `for %%a in (D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) do if exist %%a:\filename set mp=%%a` in a bat file. Is there anything like this in python but that will output a list of all paths to folders called desktop instead of just the first one to a file name? I have googled it but nothing has been helpful.

Comment: You can have a look at the python library "os"

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
import os
path = "C:/whatever/your/path/is"
files = os.listdir(path)
```

Comment: Sort of, the problem is I don't know the path, I am trying to find the path to all instances of a folder with a certain name and add them to a list variable for easy use. for example if i am looking for all variables called Documents and there are four folders called documents the output list should look something like [C:\Users\bob\Documents, C:\Users\dylan\Documents, C:\Users\Public\Documents, H:\backups\Documents].